# Can a .NET component be used from a COM component?

Tags: .net, com, interop

Can a .NET component be used from a COM component?

Comment: Your question is not so clear.

Answer (score 4):

Read this

[Calling a .NET Component from a COM Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973802.aspx)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

As [thoroughly explained in this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/cominterop.aspx), there are two ways to do it:

1. Early binding, which involves using a tool (Type library Importer, or [tlbimp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx(v=vs.90).aspx)) to create a binary file (a .NET assembly) which contains metadata necessary for the CLR to instantiate the [Runtime Callable Wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe.aspx) for the COM object. This provides all the strong typing benefits, because you can reference the generated assembly and use these classes like any other .NET classes in your code.
2. Late binding, which uses the `Type.InvokeMember` method to invoke methods of a COM object by their name, during runtime. Since this approach is weakly typed, it's more error prone than early binding, but it also allows greater flexibility.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: oh, crap, the question was about consuming .NET from COM, not vice versa. Have to run now, I'll fix it later.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it (like mentioned in the other answers).

It basically boils down to *exposing your .NET component as a COM component* (this can be done by signing your assembly and just flipping a switch [Make assembly COM-Visible] in the *[Assembly Information Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h52t681(VS.80).aspx)*, but good practice demands to implement an interface, and expose only the interface using the [ComVisibleAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h52t681(VS.80).aspx)).

This way, your COM component can talk to the .NET component as if it is also a COM component.